# I got an "Error at line 2, character 4: Parse error. primary expression expected"

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I don't know why I got an error on this custom javascript variable in Google Tag Manager?

I'm trying to populate the purchase-event for the facebook pixel with values. SO this is my way of getting the information from the datalayer into the purchase-event. I'm not sure if i'm doing this right but i can't test it in preview mode beacuse of the error message!

```
var facebookArray = [];

{{DLV - Products}}.forEach(function(product) {

  facebookArray.push({

    sku: product.sku,

    quantity: product.quantity,

    item_price: product.price,

  });
});
```

The Datalayer varible {{DLV - Products}} is coming from transactionProducts in the datalayer (Yes we don't use enhanced ecommerce).

This is what the facebbok purchase event looks like (custom HTML-tag):

```
<script>


fbq('track', 'Purchase',{

 products: '[{{custom JS - transaction products}}]',


value: '{{DLV - Ecommerce - TransactionTotal}}',   


currency: 'SEK'


});

</script>
```

Comment: I think the editor doesn't understand moustache templating, but the OP doesn't use moustache templating anyway, hence the error

Comment: Okay! But then how do I get the information from the datalayer varible in to the custom javscript varible? Sorry for stupied questions but my brain dosen't work anymor :P

Comment: can you fix the code - it looks worse after the edit :p

Comment: does it make more sencs now?

Comment: yes, as long as that code is preprocessed by something that replaces `{{DLV - Products}}` with an array

Comment: thanks for awnsering! I just have no idea have to move forward.

Comment: what do you believe `{{DLV - Products}}` should be?

Comment: 5. transactionProducts: Array(2)
1.  0:
1. category: "tickets"
2. name: "Adult"
3. price: 125
4. quantity: 1
5. sku: "Adult"
6. __proto__: Object
2. 1:
1. category: "tickets"
2. name: "Pensioner"
3. price: 100
4. quantity: 1
5. sku: "Pensioner"
6. __proto__: Object

Comment: I want to get SKU:s and quantity and price from this standard ecommerce-array! Soeey for the bad code but this is copied from the datalayer after a purchase

Comment: well `{{Anything here}}` is not javascript - yuo must have some sort of pre-processing system or something for you to use that syntax

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have copied your variable code fully. This means, that you haven't provided the full required syntax for GTM's custom javascript variable. As per the inline help:

> This field should be a JavaScript function that returns a value using
>   the 'return' statement. If the function does not explicitly return a
>   value, it will return undefined and your container may not behave as
>   expected. Below is an example of this field:   function() {
>       var now = new Date();
>       return now.getTime();   }

So you need to wrap your code into a function, and also return the calculated, processed values:

```
function () {
  var facebookArray = [];

  {{DLV - Products}}.forEach(function(product) {

    facebookArray.push({

      sku: product.sku,

      quantity: product.quantity,

      item_price: product.price,

    });
  });

  return facebookArray;
}
```